# Editing HTML table with PHP DOM

Tags: php, html, dom

I've tried to add a column to a table I've loaded to the DOM function but can't get this code working.

```
<?php

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<table>
    <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th> 
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td> 
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>');

$tr = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');

$th = $dom->createElement('th', 'Comment');
$tr->item(0)->appendChild($th);
```

Comment: You add a `th` element to the table. This works fine. What is your problem?

Comment: @PhilippPalmtag How can I get this to save to a variable so I can output this to a user?

Comment: I used `echo $dom->saveHTML();` to output the HTML.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks.

Comment: I have put the solution into an anwer for you to accept.

Comment: For further reference, see [saveHTML()](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. You successfully add a new `th` element to the DOM tree. But you need to output it to the browser with

```
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

The output in HTML is:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <th>Firstname</th>
               <th>Lastname</th>
               <th>Age</th>
               <th>Comment</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>Jill</td>
               <td>Smith</td>
               <td>50</td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```